# send emails to specific addresses based on value of fields

Tags: 7, emails

I have field_a with select list of 10 value

when field_b is checked
and
when a value of field_a is alfa or beta or ecc, send email to address1 or 2 or ecc

I try with custom module for advance control of features

```
function test_mail_node_submit($node, $form, &$form_state) {
 if($node->type == 'rso') {
  if ($node->field_b['und'][0]['value'] == TRUE){
   if ($node->field_a['und'][0]['tid'] == '10'){
    mail('example1@mail.com', 'example2@mail.com', 'example text');
   }
  }
 }
}
```

I did not understand how to use [drupal_mail](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21mail.inc/function/drupal_mail/7.x), or hook_menu hook_mail_alter

Comment: Are you trying to achieve this with Drupal 7 or 8 ?

Comment: Drupal 7....I'm sorry for forgeditfulness

Comment: I tried rules, but I can not set the address from the check field

Answer (score 0):

I am a little confused about your question. But here is an example for you to send email using hook_mail. Hope you can get some idea from this:

```
/**
* Implement hook_mail() function
*/
function test_mail_node_mail($key, &$message, $params) {
   $headers = array(
     'MIME-Version' => '1.0',
     'Content-Type' => 'text/html; charset=UTF-8; format=flowed; delsp=yes',
     'Content-Transfer-Encoding' => '8Bit',
     'X-Mailer' => 'Drupal'
   );

   foreach ($headers as $key => $value) {
      $message['headers'][$key] = $value;
   }

   $message['subject'] = $params['subject'];
   $message['body'] = $params['body'];
}

/**
* Implement hook_submit() function
*/
function test_mail_node_submit($node, $form, &$form_state) {
   if($node->type == 'rso') {
     if ($node->field_b['und'][0]['value'] == TRUE){
       if ($node->field_a['und'][0]['tid'] == '10'){
          // mail('example1@mail.com', 'example2@mail.com', 'example text');
          $valid_email = array('example1@mail.com', 'example2@mail.com');
          $params = array(
             'body' => 'Your body text',
             'subject' => 'This is a subject',
          );
          drupal_mail('test_mail_node', 'HTML', $valid_email, 'en', $params));
       }
     }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the reply.

I write this code:

```
function test_mail_mail($key, &$message, $params) {

 switch($key) {
    case 'one':
      $message['subject'] = "mail-1";
      $message['body'][] ="example text 2";
      break;

    case 'two':
      $message['subject'] = "mail-2";
      $message['body'][] = "example text 2";
      break;
  }
}

function test_mail_node_submit($node, $form, &$form_state){
    if($node->type == 'alfa') {
        if ($node->field_q['und'][0]['tid'] == '100'){
                $node->field_2['und'][0]['value'] = 'Mr.Brown';

// drupal_mail($module, $key, $to, $language, $params = array(), $from = NULL, $send = TRUE)
drupal_mail('test_mail', 'mail-1', '<example1.mail.com>', language_default(), $params, 'example2.mail.com');

        }
    }
}
```

it works but do not understand how to use $ params. In the Body of the Message I would like to insert some variable, for example: $node->field_2['und'][0] ['value'] ((Mr.Brown))

Comment: This is php question. You can use dot. For example, based on you body text, you can write like this: `$message['body'][] = "example text 2".$node->field_2['und'][0]['value'];`

Comment: I had already tried, result: two errors notice
Notice: Undefined variable: node in test_mail_mail()
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in test_mail_mail()

Comment: I have add: $node = menu_get_object();

....sorry but I'm a beginner :p